# Identify what CSS rule is adding arrows next to list elements

Tags: html, wordpress, css, plugin

I'm trying to identify the CSS that is generating the arrows next to the items in the "Recent Jobs" section of my [site's homepage](https://www.tridentembeddedsolutions.com/) (scroll down, sidebar on right).  The code is being generated by a plugin, and I need to identify the CSS generating the arrows, so that I can change (override) it.  I've tried using Chrome's DOM Inspector, but no joy.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that your CSS isn't "obfuscated".   Obfuscated would replace human readable names with gobbletygook.    Your CSS appears to be "minified" where whitespace is removed for file size and performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try right-clicking (or command-click on a Mac) over the element with Firefox and selecting 'Inspect element' from the menu. This reveals that it is an unordered list with a background image styling the list on line 255 of style.css.

```
.widget ul li {
    background: url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 10px;
    padding: 5px 0 8px 18px;
    color: #262626;
}
```

There is also a style removing the list style (to be replaced with the background image) in frontend.css on line 1 - probably minified CSS all on one line.

```
.rp4wp-related-job_listing > ul li.job_listing a .meta li, .rp4wp-related-job_listing > ul li.no_job_listings_found a .meta li, ul.job_listings li.job_listing a .meta li, ul.job_listings li.no_job_listings_found a .meta li {
    list-style: none outside;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When looking for CSS rules that put things between, before, or after, it is important to look for `:before` and `:after` nodes and rules.     Those are typically shown in the inspector inside the element.

Firefox's DOM inspector is able to find it.  I just had to open the `li` node and there the `::after` node containing the arrow is inside:

[image]
It appears to be caused by this rule in [frontend.css](https://www.tridentembeddedsolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-manager/assets/css/frontend.css?ver=4.7):

`.widget ul.job_listings li.job_listing ul.meta li:after{padding:0 0 0 .5em;content:"\2023"}`

Comment: I see other answers have found different CSS for different arrows in the same section.   I hadn't even seen the ones they point out -- I thought there were smudges on my screen.   I suspect that the arrows in this answer are fine and it is the smudges you are actually trying to get rid of.    I'm leaving this answer because I included some general advice that may be helpful to others in similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot with erroneous arrows]

I assume you are referring to the smudge-like arrows in the bottom-left corners of the list-items, rather than the arrows between the list items.

Using Chrome's object inspector, there appears to be a background image that results in this (seemingly erroneous) "arrow". In `styles.css?ver=4.7` on line #255:

```
.widget ul li {
    background: url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 10px;
    adding: 5px 0 8px 18px;
    color: #262626;
}
```

After removing the `background` property, the arrows are removed:

[image: Same image with arrows removed]

Comment: Those are the fanciest screenshots I've ever seen.  :)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks :) - I've been trialling [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm). (I would have preferred the edge/background to be transparent, but it seems to be a non-configurable opaque white?)